# How do I delete a cloned HTML element with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A couple of days ago I had placed a question regarding the cloning of an HTML element. I got the JQuery function to work, but I'd also like the element(, in this case a textarea) to be deleted if a user requires it. I've tried to legally steal several solutions from the net, but I cannot get this to work. I'm sure I'm doing something horribly wrong. Please have a look at this bit of code to try and help me get to know what exactly is incorrect.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    #parse("inc/Demo.html")
    <div id="parent" class="no-print">

        <div id="content">
            <form>
                <br>
                <div id ="div_Upper">
                    <a href="?add_item=true" class="button_Upper green square">Email Form</a>
                    <a href="?add_item=true" class="button_Upper green square">Save Form</a>
                    <a href="?add_item=true" class="button_Upper green square">Change Form</a>
                    <a href="?add_item=true" class="button_Upper green square">new</a>
                    <a href="http://localhost:8080/servoy-service/velocity/testportaal/Algemeneinformatie.html" type ="button" class ="button_Upper green square">Portal</a>
                </div>

                <div id="div_Form">
                    <div>
                        <div name="question" id="form_List">
                            <br>
                            <input autofocus name="title" type="text"                    
                                id="title" value="Titel" onfocus="
                                    if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="
                                    if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div id="form_Content">
                            <br>
                            <textarea name="Content[]" type="text" id="Content[]"
                            onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';"
                            onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
                            </textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button id="AddTextarea">Add</button><button id="remove">Remove</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="div_Form2">
                    <div id="buttons_Save_Delete_Edit">
                        <a href="?add_item=true"class="button_Edit_Save_Delete red square" type="button">Delete</a>
                        <a href="?add_item=true" class="button_Edit_Save_Delete green square" type="button">Save</a>
                        <a href="?add_item=true" class="button_Edit_Save_Delete green square" type="button">Edit</a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Question type</label>
                        <div id="form_list">
                            <select id="Select">
                                <option value="Text">Text</option>  
                                <option value="Date">Date</option>
                                <option value="Scale">Scale</option>
                                <option value="Tekstarea">Textarea</option>
                                <option value="Checkboxes">Checkboxes</option>
                                <option value="multiple_Choice">Multiple-Choice</option>
                                <option value="Choose from a list">Choose from a list</option>
                                onder require>masker dd,mm,jjjj
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div>
                    <div id="form_List">
                        <label>Mask</label>
                        <div id="form_list">
                            <select id="Select" >
                                <option value="date">{Date}DD-MM-JJJJ</option>
                                <option value="mobile_number">{M-nummer}__-________</option>  
                                <option value="house_number">{H-nummer}___-_______</option>  
                                <option value="ponskaart nummer">Ponskaart nummer</option>
                                <option value="klanten nummer">Klanten nummer</option>
                            </select>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div id="form_List">
                        <label>Question title</label>
                        <input type="text" name="Vraag Titel" id="list" value="..." onfocus="
                            if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="
                            if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div id="form_List">
                        <label>Help text</label>
                        <input type="text" name="Help_tekst" id="list" value="..." onfocus="
                            if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="
                            if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div id="form_List"> 
                        <label>Required</label>
                        <div id="form_list">
                            <input id="checkboxes"type="checkbox" name="Required" value="Required"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                #parse("Form/Textarea.html")
                <div>
                    <div id="button_Add_Question">
                        <a href="?add_item=true" class="Add_Question green square" onclick="">+</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div >
                    <button  id="Button_Done" class="buttons_Done green square" type="submit">Done</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button  id="button_Complete" class="buttons_Complete_Add green square" type="submit">Complete form</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        #parse("inc/footer.html")
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#AddTextarea').click(function() {
        $clone=$('textarea[name="Content[]"]:first').clone();
        console.log($clone);
        $('#form_Content').append($clone);
        return false;
    });

    $("#remove").click(function(e) {
        $(this).closest('textarea[name="Content[]"]:first').remove();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

And also a link to the **JSFiddle**:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FFakkel/hcJGk/5/)

Comment: You are duplicating ids in your added text area. You also have an invalid name/id `Content[]`.

Comment: @anthony - Remove Button, fariz - so it shd remove 1st or last ?

Comment: Suggestion : disable remove when its only one textarea.

Comment: @TrueBlueAssie - The idea behind the square brackets was to make some sort of an array and have an incrementing int in between the brackets to make the id's unique. As a complete greenhorn, I tend to not finish my work due to the frustration of not being able to get things done like you guys are able to do.

Comment: @Bhavin - I'd like it to remove only the last textarea. And I'll try doing that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the line:

```
$(this).closest('textarea[name="Content[]"]:first').remove();
```

replace it with:

```
$('textarea[name="Content[]"]:last').remove();
```

This way it will remove the last added textarea.

*From jQuery docs:* (http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .closest() method searches through these elements and their ancestors
>   in the DOM tree and constructs a new jQuery object from the matching
>   elements.

In your case, it searches `this`, and hence is unable to find a textarea in the set or in ancestry of the remove button.

**Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hcJGk/9/**

Answer (score 0):

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hcJGk/11/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#AddTextarea').click(
        function() {
            $clone=$('textarea[name="Content"]:first').clone();
            console.log($clone);
           $('#form_Content').append($clone);
            return false;
    });

    $("#remove").click(function(e) {
        $(this).closest('div').find('textarea[name="Content"]:last').remove();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

There are several problems with your example. Don't use a name like "Content[]" and don't expect duplicated ID's to work on all browsers (dump the id on the textArea).

You were also applying `closest` to the `button` and expecting to find the `textarea`, but `closest` only searches back up the parents of the element.

I changed the example to find the parent DIV then remove the last textarea so that you could have multiples of these on the same page.